# At least one object must implement IComparable error

Tags: c#, linq

I have an issue and I'm unable to resolve it. Have a look at my code.

```
CustomerProductivity.Add(new ChartDataViewModel
{
    Series = new List<string> { "Sales" },
    ChartType = "bar",
    Data = SalesStatistics
        .GroupBy(b => b.CustomerName)
        .Select(g => new ChartDataElement()
        {
            X = g.Key,
            Y = new List<int>() { (int)g.Sum(b => b.Sales) }
        }).OrderByDescending(f=> f.Y).Take(3).ToList(),
    ChartConfig = config
});
```

The scenario is that I want to get the Top 3 Customers with highest sales. But it gives me an error as "At least one object must implement IComparable". Surprisingly, I've tried to order by customer name and it worked fine, but it's not fine if I order by sales.

Comment: How can you order by a list?

Comment: I think you wanted `}).OrderByDescending(f=> f.Y.First()).Take(3).ToList(),`

Comment: Why are you putting the result of the aggregation in a list?

Comment: @Luaan he creates an `ChartDataElement` this is `Y` type, he don't have a choice, i think.

Comment: @adricadar Ah, good point. Not very practical for LINQ... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leppie mentioned you order by a `List` and your program don't know how to **compare this 2 lists**.

```
List<int> > List<int> // How i compare this? by Count? by elements? what property of elements? and so one
```

I see that you have **only 1 element** in your list. Based on this you can order by `.First()` (and only) element from list.

```
CustomerProductivity.Add(new ChartDataViewModel
{
    Series = new List<string> { "Sales" },
    ChartType = "bar",
    Data = SalesStatistics
        .GroupBy(b => b.CustomerName)
        .Select(g => new ChartDataElement()
        {
            X = g.Key,
            Y = new List<int>() { (int)g.Sum(b => b.Sales) }
        }).OrderByDescending(f=> f.Y.First()).Take(3).ToList(),
    ChartConfig = config
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My doubt is why we need a list to hold a single value, should n't

```
<pre>
   Y = new List<int>() { (int)g.Sum(b => b.Sales) }
</pre>
should be 
<pre>
  Y =  (int)g.Sum(b => b.Sales) \\\\ as the sum will a int. 
</pre>
```

if I am correct , then the changing this line will correct the error.